# How do you add an API key in Swagger

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have tried several methods to add a basic API key authorization to Swagger (express swagger). Below is the relevant info from my manifest.

```
{
  ...
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "swagger-express-mw": "^0.1.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

I believe I have registered the security definitions in the YAML configuration.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  ...

# Set up security for the API
securityDefinitions:
  defaultApiKey:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: defaultApiKey

security:
    - defaultApiKey: []
```

To finish this configuration I thought I would only need to register the middleware in the SwaggerExpress.create() function. Below is my entire app.js as it currently stands.

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  // Serve the Swagger documents and SwaggerUi
  app.use(swaggerExpress.runner.swaggerTools.swaggerUi());

  // Install security
  app.use(swaggerExpress.swaggerSecurity({
    defaultApiKey: function(req, def, scopes, callback) {
      console.log("hit");
    }
  }));

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  app.listen(port);
});
```

When I attempt to use this I see the following:

```
Error initializing middleware
TypeError: swaggerExpress.swaggerSecurity is not a function
```

I have tried configuring this a few different ways with no success. Did I properly define the API key in YAML and if so what should I do to register the API key handler in my app.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by transforming the YAML definitions to the JSON format and loading the API definition this way:

```
'use strict';

// [INIT PRE-SERVER REQUIREMENTS]
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var https = require('https');


var swagger = require('swagger-tools');
var app = require('express')();
var db = require(/* db config path */);
var swaggerObject = require('./api/swagger/swagger.json');

// Configure non-Swagger related middleware and server components prior to Swagger middleware

swagger.initializeMiddleware(swaggerObject, function (middleware) {

  // Intialize middleware
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  // Setup security handlers
  app.use(middleware.swaggerSecurity({
    api_key: function(req, def, scopes, callback) {
      // API KEY LOGIC HERE
      // IF SUCCESSFUL
      callback();
    }
  });

  // Route requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter({useStubs: true, controllers: './api/controllers'}));

  // Setup documentation
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

  // Start the server
  var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    // KEY INFO
  }, app);
  httpsServer.listen(443, function() {
    console.log('Server created and listening for requests on port 443.');
  });
});
```

Comment: what is swagger.json i have only the yaml ?

Comment: @danielad you can convert your .yaml to .json with the swagger-codegen tool https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#to-generate-a-sample-client-library

Comment: i m using swagger-express-md ? do i need swagger-tools or what ? how can the two needs and used please?

Comment: @danielad Check out this link, it may be the easier way to go. The swagger code gen site is really easy compared to downloading a standalone tool: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/g2T56P1bh04

Comment: am  thinking of not generating or using a tool. i love to code but am confued about which nodejs library to use to do the job. Thanks!

Comment: I am surprised you are able to catch it using your handler defined in `app.js` (or `index.js`) here. I tried the same way, and couldn't get the handler to catch my Auth param (passed as a header param). Instead, I had to modify `swagger-security.js` to do this.

Comment: @Sonny I had a lot of trouble with versions handling things differently. Hopefully future versions will make functions like this easier.

Comment: Hey folks... (1) ~yaml.js~ **yamljs** have been around for a while. (2) I prefer YAML over JSON because of verbosity matters. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late, but for future reference.
With swagger-express-mw, this is how you can do it (it works for me):

```
config: {
    appRoot: __dirname,
    swaggerSecurityHandlers: {
        defaultApiKey: function(req, authOrSecDef, scopesOrApiKey, callback) {
        // code here
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it is helpful for someone.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "code here" section? I am looking for an example of how to implement the logic and every swagger-tools example I have found simply says "logic goes here" or "..." instead of providing an _actual example_.

Comment: That's where you write something something like ```if(authSuccess) callback(); else callback(new Error('bad username'))```. It is just your code with the auth mechanism you decided to use in your app, where you call callback() with no arguments if success and callback(error) if the authentication failed.